# Why is it correct?

Tags: grammar

**Hamlet is a tragedy written by Shakespeare between 1599 and 1601.**
Shouldn’t we say that **which is written**? When can we omit which is?
Also is it correct to say:
**insulin and glucagon are two hormones released by pancreas**? Not which are released.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can any relative clauses be reduced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346273/can-any-relative-clauses-be-reduced) Or [relative pronoun with ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/551067/about-relatives-pronoun-with-bev/551096#551096)? Or [when can the relative pronouns -who-which-that-etc be safely omitted?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/406389/when-can-the-relative-pronouns-who-which-that-etc-be-safely-omitted/406392#406392)

Comment: We _could_ say 'which **was** written', but it's quote common to leave out **which is/was/are/were** when the meaning is clear without it.

Comment: [This question will probably be closed.] Please look up: omitting "that" or "which".